# Search for string in tuples inside pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, search, tuples

I am trying to search for a string '3' within 'any' cell and across all columns inside a Dataframe of tuples which looks like this:

```
df = 
    Group_1     Group_2      Group_3         Group_4         Group_5        Group_6
0   (apple, 10) (grape, 2)  (watrmelon, 1)  (banana, 10)    (orange, 2)    (lemon, 4)
1   (orange, 11)(banana, 4) (pear, 11)      (apple, 2)      (grape, 3)      None
2   None        (lemon, 3)  (carrot, 5)      None            None           None
3   None         None       (tomato, 6)      None            None           None

type(df['Group_2'][2][1])
Output: str

type(df['Group_2'][2])
Output: tuple
```

`columns = ['Group_1', 'Group_2', 'Group_3', 'Group_4', 'Group_5', 'Group_6']`

Starting with an "empty" (false) mask:

```
mask = pd.Series(data=False, index=df.index)
mask[:5]

0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool


for i in columns:
    mask = mask | df[i].str.contains('3')
subset = df[mask]
subset[:3]
```

Output:

```
Group_1 Group_2 Group_3 Group_4 Group_5 Group_6
```

I was expecting to get a result like this:

```
Output 
        Group_1     Group_2      Group_3         Group_4         Group_5        Group_6
    1   None         None        None             None          (grape, 3)        None
    2   None        (lemon, 3)   None             None           None           None
```

Can anyone suggest a better method of getting this done?
I have been trying to get this working with pandas and it seems like it'll be either too difficult to achieve and should pursue a different approach/library or something easy that I am doing incorrectly(obviously).

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought the best approach would be to iterate through all rows/columns and replacing values where the contents do not contain the string "3". This might not work too well if your dataset is large, where you could then transpose the columns to rows, then use a mask to see if the row with all of your group information contains the string "3". Below is the code to exclude records if they do not contain "3".

```
# Get column names
col = list(df)

# Loop through each column
for column in col:
    # loop through each row
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if "3" not in row[column]:
            row[column] = False # Or another designator
```

Just make sure that all of your columns are strings. You can do this with a `df.astype(str)` to convert the entire df to a string.

Comment: Unfortunately the column sizes (no. rows) in the real dataframe range up to a several thousand rows. The answer provided works well for a small data set but it breaks down for larger dataframes. One thing that seemed to have affected the results is the string check in your last line which was helpful. I'll continue playing with it. Thanks

Comment: Ignore the above it works well (bad testing procedure).

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
df=df.applymap(lambda x: x if x!='None' and [int(s) for s in x if s.isdigit()][0]==3 else None).dropna(axis=0,how='all')
print(df)
```

Output

```
  Group_1     Group_2 Group_3 Group_4     Group_5 Group_6
1    None        None    None    None  (grape, 3)    None
2    None  (lemon, 3)    None    None        None    None
```